# About the function $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{i}}{1-z^{i}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I think the study of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{i}}{1-z^{i}}$ its important because if $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{i}}{1-z^{i}} = a_{0} + a_{1} z + a_{2} z^2 \cdots$, then

$a_{i} = 2$ if $i$ is prime and $i > 1$, and $a_{i} > 2$ in the rest of cases.

I know that exist an asymptotic formula for the $a_{i}$ of $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-z^{i}}$  (formula of the numbers of partitions of an positive integer) but I don't know if exist a similar approach for the $a_{i}$ of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{i}}{1-z^{i}}$

I think that the proof of the existence of that convergence formula must be very difficult, or impossible.

Comment: Can you find a description for the exact value of $a_i$ (which include the $i$ prime case)?  EG For $a_k z^k$, which values of $z^i / ( 1 - z^k)$ will contribute a term?

Comment: For example if $i$ is not a prime number, contributes the divisors of $i$. For example for $a_{12}$ contributes $\frac{z^{i}}{1-z^{i}}$ with $i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12$ , the divisors of 12, hence $a_{12} = 6$

Comment: Yes, but that dont provide an asymtotic formula for $d(n)$

Comment: Clearly it has no asymptotic formula right? It takes on the value 2 infinitely often, and can also take on arbitrarily large values.

Comment: Sorry. I means a convergence formula of d(n), based on trigonometric functions or Fourier transform.

Comment: That's still not clear. What's a convergence formula? Perhaps give an example of the type of statement you're looking for? (The example need not be true; just so we understand what sort of thing you want.)

Comment: Something like that:

$a_{n} = \sum_{j = 0}^{k} \left(c_{j} e^{i j} + c_{-j} e^{-i j}\right) $ for $n< k$ or something similar, a sum of terms that aproximates d(n) without factoring n into prime numbers. But I think that this not exist.

Comment: Are you aware of the q-polygamma function ?

Comment: I think its more related to calculate the $a_{i}$ of the series expansion of Lambert series

Comment: It is well known that $d(n)=2$ for infinitely many $n$ and $d(n)>2^{[1-o(1)]\log n/\log\log n}$ for infinitely many $n$, so it does not have an asymptotic formula in terms of elementary functions.